# Execute Task.Run on main thread

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am using monotouch/Xamarin for an iOS app.

The documentation for [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> Queues the specified work to run on the `ThreadPool` and returns a task
> handle for that work.

Which essentially indicates that it could run on any thread `ThreadPool`.

I want to do something like:

```
Task.Run(async () => await PerformTask());
```

but have it run on the main thread. Normally I would write it using [`BeginInvokeOnMainThread`](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction)/) as follows:

```
BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await PerformTask());
```

But I am doing this in shared code and do not want to use iOS specific calls. Is there a way for me to tell Task.Run() to invoke the action on the main thread?

Comment: Is the currently executing code in the main thread or not?

Comment: @Servy, in my current context it is safe to make that assumption. But if there is a more general answer I would like that too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to run `PerformTask` in the current thread, instead of a thread pool thread, you simply need to *not* call `Task.Run`.  Just use:

```
PerformTask();
```

and you're done.  If you want to only continue executing the rest of the method when that task is done, then `await` it:

```
await PerformTask();
```

There is no reason to call `Task.Run` here for you, nor is there any reason to create a lambda that `awaits` the method for no particular reason (you could just call it directly if you wanted to start it from a thread pool thread).

Comment: One of my biggest dislikes with async/await and task is that they are lacking the feature "Execute on main". I want to do this later, but i want to do it at the next step of the main event loop (no need for locks).

Comment: @Dabaus That async methods capture and use the synchronization context means that they do that *by default*.  You need to go out of your way to make them *not* do that.  That's the whole point of this answer, so your comment confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a task from the main thread you could use TaskSchedluer's method FromCurrentSynchronizationContext().

```
Task t = new Task(() =>
{
    ...
});
t.Start(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

This can be useful sometimes. However, if you want to use this technique to bypass thread checks (for example, modifying properties of form controls in a windows app), you should rethink your design. Use tasks for calculations or other non-UI operations and update the UI from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MainQueue.cs: https://gist.github.com/gering/0aa9750d3c7d14b856d0ed2ba98374a8

It is for Xamarin Forms applications. You have to call Init() from main thread once, but then you are able to ensure execution on main thread.